# undefined reference to `shm_open' - how can I pinpoint the culprit?

Tags: cmake, arm, real-time, ld

I am trying to build a simple program against a library, which itself depends on librt. The library compiles just fine and the `-lrt` flag is used there. The program also builds fine on amd64 using cmake - but on arm64, it fails. This is not cross-compilation, but directly building it on the target. I'm using a normal cmake build system (cmake ..; make).

The exact same build system can also compile a different program, which uses the same library, but not the same functions from it.

Here is the build error:

```
[100%] Linking C executable mrun-talker
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libsec-common.so: undefined reference to `shm_open'
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libsec-common.so: undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
```

And here is the linker command:

```
/usr/bin/cc CMakeFiles/sec-talker.dir/main.c.o -o sec-talker  -lsec-common -lsec-rosc -lsec-api -ltert -lgcov -lm -lrt -lpthread
```

The linker command does contain the `-lrt` flag at the end of the command and the lrt.so is available on the target.

Is there a chance that although the library compiles just fine, it does not properly link and causes this error later when I try to use it?

Full cmake-file:

```
get_filename_component(ProjectId ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
string(REPLACE " " "_" ProjectId ${ProjectId})
project(${ProjectId})
set(ExecName ${ProjectId})

enable_language(C)

find_package(Threads)

add_executable(${ExecName} main.c)

target_link_libraries(
    ${ExecName}
    # sec libraries
    sec-common
    sec-rosc
    sec-api
    tert
    # system libraries
    gcov
    m
    Threads::Threads
    rt
)

link_directories("/usr/local/lib")

install(TARGETS ${ExecName})
```

/edit

I used ldd to check the linking of the libsec-common. Here is the result of the (working) amd64 version:

```
# ldd /usr/lib/libsec-common.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7e922000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffa350ef000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffa356ec000)
```

And of the (not-working) arm64 version.

```
# ldd /usr/lib/libsec-common.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffb2dc6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffb2c26000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffb2d9b000)
```

I don't see an issue here tbh.

Comment: Can you post the exact linker command that is used?  Is `-lrt` literally at the end?  In particular, is it specified after `-lsec-common`?

Comment: Can you please *show* your CMake file in your question post as text? Also, can you please add the *full* linker command as you described in your question post?

Comment: I added the requested parts.

Comment: `undefined reference` in the **already built** `libsec-common.so` library signals about problems with library itself or with the environment where it is used. This library **itself** should contain references to all other needed libraries. And, if those needed libraries are the same ones as used when `libsec-common.so` was built, then no undefined references should be found. How have you built `libsec-common.so` library? On the target machine too, or by some other way?

Comment: The library is also built on the target machine.

More precisely:

Using GitLab-CI, I build everything within docker-containers (from the same image) on an ARM64 machine on AWS. The projects are then packaged into Debian packages. In the CI to build the actual program I install all the dependencies from the debian packages using the before_script.

What trips me up is that the same pipeline works for the amd64 architecture, but has this issue for the arm64 architecture.

I will investigate the library some more. Are there any tools one can use to check linking in a binary?

Comment: I used ldd and added the info above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the dependency itself did not correctly link it's dependency.